# Parameter estimation in Dynamic Linear Models

Tags: maximum-likelihood, kalman-filter, state-space-models, dlm

I am currently developing a DLM of the following form

$$\underset{k \times 1} {y_t} = \underset{k \times n}A \underset{n \times 1}{\theta_t} + \epsilon_t$$
$$\theta_t = \mu + \underset{n \times n}B\theta_{t-1} + \eta_t$$

where $\epsilon_t$ and $\eta_t$ are uncorrelated normally distributed errors.

I know how to get filtered and smoothed estimates of the hidden parameters $(\theta_t)_t$ when matrices $A$ and $B$ are known. However, assume matrix $B$ has unknown parameters in it, how am I supposed to estimate them using MLE? Without knowing $B$, I cannot have any filtered or smoothed estimates of $(\theta_t)_t$ yet, so I cannot figure out how to use just the observed data $(y_t)_t$ to have an estimation of those parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Given some set of parameter values $\boldsymbol{\beta}$ you can construct $B$ and run the Kalman filter. It turns out the Kalman filter can be used to recursively calculate the marginal likelihood (see this [paper](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v039i02) by Tusell). The general idea is to factorize the likelihood function into a product of conditional likelihoods, where we sequentially evaluate the likelihood of each observation given all previous observations.

In R you could write a function, taking parameter values $\boldsymbol{\beta}$ as inputs, which

1. builds matrix $B$;
2. runs the Kalman filter;
3. calculates and returns the marginal log-likelihood using the formula in the [paper](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v039i02).

You can then maximize this function using a general purpose non-linear optimization algorithm. Be warned that this type of likelihood can sometimes be very difficult to maximize.

You can probably do step 2 using an off-the-shelf implementation which will be less prone to numerical rounding errors than a transcription of the matrix formulas.